# Polar Coordinates - find area enclosed by curve

Tags: calculus

> Please find the area enclosed by the following curve:
>   $$r=3(1+\cos(\theta))$$
>   I know the area
>   $$A=2\int_a^b\frac{1}{2}{r^2}d\theta$$
>   and for the sake of argument let's allow
>   $$A=\frac{9}{4}sin{2\theta}+\frac{27}{2}\theta+18sin\theta+ c$$
>   what I don't know is how to choose the bounds for computing the definite integral - I think I know
>   $$r=0, cos\theta=-1, \theta=\pi,3\pi$$
>   but where to from here?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169000/find-the-area-enclosed-by-the-curve-r-23-cos-theta?rq=1).

Comment: I would consider sketching the curve.

Comment: How do you know the area $A$ in advance? If you had this information why do you then need to determine the lower and upper bounds of $\theta$ to then compute the definite integral. On second your $A$ doesn't seem consistent with how it is defined as a definite integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the area $A$ can be expressed as

$$\begin{align}
A&=2\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{3(1+\cos \theta)}r\,dr\,d\theta\\\\
&=9\int_0^{\pi}(1+\cos \theta)^2\,d\theta\\\\
&=9\int_0^{\pi}(1+2\cos \theta+\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta\\\\
&=\frac{27\pi}{2}
\end{align}$$